# How do I accept a generic return type for my function in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

**Update: TSPlayground link**

[Click Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAygUQMIBUCSB5AcnAXPAU2CgEtwkQAbSo08GAXhgG8BYAKBhgCIJaywAfRJgAZiG742nLj1JQaknmjEhCxAdwA0HWTwgBXAEbzF+bgAkC1NQHUQAJ0oATAITbds7s4IRgDkgAHOjAlbgAZRwIAWxggw1jnKkcYCBJYAENogigtGFBIWhyDAgcYDOcgkj8RAHMYa3S8vmcYSqyYMHADaOiAT06SIwALBoNq6JBW0jBgEmcDMFgDWEoMqJy25IcCGGiM2rAM8soSAEcDDtKM2AA3KhXAm4A6GABVWAB3apIGsBJYhU9iIATBbgR-lk8hdqp0QNAHAZWgQAB6lOYwKA3AQwAzULKgByBUqpAw1QLpGCUEBGRykCCDCCUXGZU4wwINFENY6gXpTNQFPgXF4wAAi4wZGRWMTB1jGsRIAQMOy21LKIh4ngAvhwdewOAB6ABURt0RpgKGGu0+GQGxyMGTSwFS-HoEGGIDxrSMuwRBmIyoIzjNBo4UD6xJgACFHSRgHBXWBGCxPKYCPgEXUANyeQwmdI0DNQAJgWo5mQ+PwBYICIslsu68uGk1mi1WmA2u0ujT0b5QUbADIOZwM92elwwH2pYv+qCB4OcI2h9jhyNIIfOBM9pNMaRcNN17OedIxCBSTxcOPgLBZdPT+vlvQH+9HmRcSv+IIhQ+lx8wLXlgBHDNqai5ttatrlN2IQdukA5WsAADWQZxFAp4wAAFKcyFQQ4IAVPsgQAJSpB6XqTr6M4BjsC4wEuYYRrsSAIchm6Jsme4wAA2shfQ-rUAC655vm0vifjW4D8X+XDACxQb4LSVAEBkYB-kB7DqSBraWrsq6+DAICiNBAgMp8wxxqMQ6+gYgSBHSQYhgxkZwDZdkOGhbHbigjEMkwMZOluMEAD4wOuw6BTiIXMUQrEReATbsMaoF0TAACC+RUDQ24GUZfDbhAjkrox6ghBQ1Dsbung8QQfEvqWQnwK59meSE3nEhAgEJUlrYICixYZMQDLODcxyiHhsT9r67G1CQ4JJlAaiTTAoiLNurYAAJPA4HS8eBMC7YZmLtnlMELTAtSbMNWLLeNG07HODiQHtV2jeNR27DsFy+B5xngIVqJubAgqwBdUBxWAoojcmAA8KCcmhYAjo1tnNeDbW+AAfBhni8fxOjsER+BwwwGMpjIwO-WA+AuSj7lBmjPnJogqCYDg1V9AJCWXkZGEnQIJH3cqSZ8-FwEyP2eGfJ0BBSwgDh4Q4GEAOSWrCItJsMjpwrAPoQnE0SBDQ2RLEGrhK0RnUcEAA)

---

I currently got a function which extracts data from a `.json` file with section information, each section can be of one of three types.

```js
/**
 * The types of sections which are supported
 */
type SupportedSectionTypes = BasicSection | CardSection | CheckedSection;

/**
 * A collection of sections
 */
type SectionCollection = {
  [key: string]: SupportedSectionTypes;
};

/**
 * All the sections which are available for the website
 */
export const SECTIONS: SectionCollection = sections; // <-- `sections` is the imported json

/**
 * Extracts data from the section given to the function
 * @param key The key of the section to get data from
 * @returns The data from the requested section
 */
export const getSectionData = <T = SupportedSectionTypes>(key: string): T => {
  const section: SupportedSectionTypes = SECTIONS[key];

  if (section) return section;

  throw new Error('This section has not been implemented!');
};
```

Currently I want to make a generic function where you can declare in the generic what the the type will be, for example:

```js
const sectionData = getSectionData<CheckedSection>("my_checked_section_key");
// return type of function should be CheckedSection
```

However this code does not compile and I get the following error

```js
  if (section) return section;
  //           ^^ Type 'SupportedSectionTypes' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  // 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which
  // could be unrelated to 'SupportedSectionTypes'.ts(2322)
```

How do I make it that the generic matches the return type

---

Update after @blackgreen's answer

```js
/**
 * Extracts data from the section given to the function
 * @param key The key of the section to get data from
 * @returns The data from the requested section
 */
export const getSectionData = <T extends SupportedSectionTypes>(
  key: string,
): T => {
  const section: SupportedSectionTypes = SECTIONS[key];

  if (section) return section;

  throw new Error('This section has not been implemented!');
};
```

The error I am getting now is

```js
  if (section) return section;
  //           ^^ Type 'SupportedSectionTypes' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  // 'SupportedSectionTypes' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'SupportedSectionTypes'.
    // Type 'BasicSection' is not assignable to type 'T'.
      'BasicSection' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but  'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'SupportedSectionTypes'.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
const section: SupportedSectionTypes = SECTIONS[key];
```

you are returning `section`, that is of type `SupportedSectionTypes`, and **may not be** `T`. That's why Typescript gives you an error.

You can force it to be considered equivalent to `T`:

```
const section: T = SECTIONS[key] as T;
```

Just note that Typescript can not know if the returning type is really `T`.

Imagine your `SECTIONS` object has a key `foo` containing a `CardSection`. The following code will be considered valid:

```
const checkedSection = <CheckedSection>getSectionData('foo')
```

But, at runtime, `checkedSection` will not contain a `CheckedSection` object.

---

If you already know which key you will face, you can properly define your `SECTIONS` object and then your generic type can be *inferred* by typescript:

```
type SectionCollection = {
  section_info: BasicSection
  foo: CheckedSection
  bar: CardSection
};

export const getSectionData = <T extends keyof SectionCollection>(key: T): SectionCollection[T] => {
  const section: SectionCollection[T] = SECTIONS[key];

  if (section) return section;

  throw new Error('This section has not been implemented!');
};

// Here Typescript understands that the returning type is `CheckedSection`
const section = getSectionData('foo');
```

Comment: This is great, very clean with a good explanation. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

First you need to tell `ts` compiler `key` is key of a `SECTIONS` then in return type you have to cast as `T`.

```
export const getSectionData = <T extends SupportedSectionTypes>(key : string): T => {
  let f = key as keyof  typeof SECTIONS;
  const section: SupportedSectionTypes =  SECTIONS[f];

  if (section) return section as T;

  throw new Error('This section has not been implemented!');
};
```

[PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAygUQMIBUCSB5AcnGBeGAbwFgAoGGAIggFNgoBLcAfQbADMRKAuIsiipUZQANjR5U0HEPDqNwlADT8B1AK4AjYWImUAEjREiZAdRAAnEQBMAhEpWCrNCMHMMADvLC6AMhZoAtjAeEGpBViDG5jAQDLAAhgE0UIowoJByyWo00fFWHgwubADmMIZxqbRWMPmJMGDgYQEAnvUMGgAWZWqFASDVjGDADFZqYLBqsCLx-sk1kf4wAfHFYPEw8SIMAI5qdTnxsABukZPuhwB0MACqsADuhQxlYAxBeUtsrzBHNC%20JqbtCvUQNBzGpqjQAB45YYwKCHJhgGBqIyJUDmdw5GJqIruOIwYwaCyMCBtCAiZEJLaA9xlSFldagAJ9CJpcC0XaXGAAER6pPik0C30M3SCDDcanMNHmUWCSMoKgAvmRlaQyAB6ABUmv4mpgKA60ru8Va6w08ViwBickRMQ6IBR1Q00tBanokpoVl16rIUGamJgACELQxgHAbeB8HxyHC4mJeKCSgBuFShLRxmgJqBuMDFFMxpwuNyeRFZnN5lX5jXa3X6w0wY2m630W0PKBdYDxcxWUkQe2OmDOmLZt1QD1e8ian2kP0BpBdqzhluRggkGPaTPD8v5ihxQIQXhrgTBdJYRKbxO5ncCDdl5MOGrOVweLx3q9K-OKqukLU6yd1o0TQ2ZsvAbOIO0NYAAGtPWCKB9xgAAKLYYOA8wQDyZZ3AASjtB1rEHF0R3dKUJxgKdfX9aUkEgmDFwjJFVxUABtGDmjfYoAF1DwfQtnxLcAOOvChgFoz1eCJSIaHiMBry-SsyGrP9yIAuEqNJEB2BAxFSTuDpQy6LsXTUdx3GJT1vUogM4BMszzHg%20jlzAFB1KjYNLSXUCAB8YHnbtPNtHyaLoOiAvAb9f1rABBNkjAYmBNO09lLJnKjZCcpBIjEJyoyPGBWJoditxKbj4Fs8zHK8FzMQgT8Iprf8EEhbN4noUkrEOdZ2HQoJ2xdeLigYH4kSgGQ%20pgdgxic2sAAFznMOo2NUpbEvG2gctGmBijmDr4QmnrZqlMdzEgVTdq6nq4XrKVdmcBykrAFL0mgLbkjCsBuU6qMAB4UDpeCwB7MrTIq97qucAA%20RClo47DeD%20vAIejCgxFgLSCCWi0YDYxK1MxRLEFQTAcGvZ7YHW19gbshywdcgh4GQdBsDgZj2E479dy0xCKcRXCjslJEecjLGUA5q70LueoaElhBzHQ8xEIAcgNIEhaRDosYaWBnV%20YIAncMQknGT0bEV7C6rIIA)